# Bootstrap 4: Add an input field in a popover

Tags: html

I would like to add an input field inside a popover using Bootstrap 4.

The following code doesn't work. The popover is empty and the input field is not rendered as it should.

**HTML**

```html
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-secondary"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-html="true"
    data-container="body"
    data-content='
    <input type="text" value="my input value">
    '>
    Popover
</button>
```

**JS**

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        delay: {
            show: 100
        }
    })
})
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to work if you move it out of the html and into the js.

```
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-secondary"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-container="body">
    Popover
</button>

$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        delay: {
            show: 100
        },
         html: true,
         sanitize: false,
         content: '<input type="text" value="my input value">'
    })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mkz2qhxu/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any reason why it doesn't work when included as an HTML attribute?